# How to randomly assign users a font in a qualtrics survey

Tags: qualtrics

I am conducting an experiment on Qualtrics. The font used in the survey is one of the variables I am testing.

I would like to use "MS Serif" to 50% of my participants, and "MS Sans Serif" to the other 50% of participants. These fonts are part of the fonts you can pick in the "look and feel" UI of Qualtrics.

I would also have to record which font each participant saw.

How do I do this?

My first idea was to create two surveys, and just have Mechanical Turk pick one of them randomly. However, my account will only let me have one active survey at a time.

Answer (score 2):

It may depend your theme, but you can try the following.

First, at the top of the Survey Flow, add a randomizer to pick one of two embedded data blocks evenly to give you a 50/50 split.  Inside the embedded data blocks assign a font-family to an embedded data variable:

```
Randomizer
 Block 1
   fontFamily = 'MS Serif' 
 Block 2
   fontFamily = 'MS Sans Serif'
```

Then under Look&Feel Advanced, add the following to the Header using Source editing:

```
<style>
#RestoredResponseBar, .Skin, .Skin .yui-skin-sam .yui-calcontainer,
.Skin button, .Skin input, .Skin select, .Skin textarea {
     font-family: ${e://Field/fontFamily};
}
</style>
```

**EDIT:**
If the style tag in the header doesn't work for you, you can try adding a custom style using JavaScript in the Header **instead**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
        var fontFamily = "${e://Field/fontFamily}";
        $('customStyles').update("#RestoredResponseBar, .Skin, "
            + ".Skin .yui-skin-sam .yui-calcontainer, .Skin button, .Skin input, "
            + ".Skin select, .Skin textarea { font-family: " + fontFamily + " }");
});
</script>
```

Note the change from double to single quotes in the embedded data assignments above.

Comment: This didn't work, but got me further. Putting the style in the Header using Source editing had no effect. However, when I used "Add custom css" (on the same Advanced page), I was able to add css that had an effect on the page. However the piped text was not evaluated. It literally asked the browser to use the font-family "${e://Field/fontFamily}". Do you know why 1) the source editing method didn't have any effect, or 2) How to get piped text to work in the "add custom css" approach?

Comment: Update: The reason the Header approach didn't work is because qualtrics doesn't seem to include the <style> element in the header html. It will allow other elements like <p>, but not <style>

Comment: The `<style>` tag in the header works for me.  Not sure why it wouldn't work for you unless you don't have markup html rights.

Comment: Qualtrics is stripping the <script> tag that I provided, just as it did with the <style> tag. Probably you are right about not having markup html rights.

Comment: If you have JavaScript rights, you could add the script to one question on each page (without the <script> tag).

Comment: Thanks for all your help so far. I've concluded that I don't have many rights on my qualtrics account. I ended up creating two surveys (one in each font that I needed) and randomly assigning users to those surveys. I learnt alot from your information thanks.