# How to access embedded data in custom css

Tags: qualtrics

In the *Look & Feel* section of a survey, under *Advanced*, you can *Add custom css*.

I'd like to access my embedded data in my custom css.

For example, I would like to do this:

```
.Skin {
    font-family: ${e://Field/fontFamily};
}
```

The above code doesn't work. The embedded data variable *fontFamily* isn't inserted into the custom css.

I am able to access embedded data in the *Header* and *Footer* elements. However, these elements do not allow me to specify styles for the rest of the document (qualtrics seem to strip any  elements you add to that section).

Comment: As you've found out, you can't use piped variables in Custom CSS. See update to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47493327/how-to-randomly-assign-users-a-font-in-a-qualtrics-survey/47499179#47499179

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to randomly assign users a font in a qualtrics survey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47493327/how-to-randomly-assign-users-a-font-in-a-qualtrics-survey)